# select only matching records from two tables

Tags: sql, oracle

I am using Oracle 10g
Here is my scenario:

I have two tables

```
class1(groupName, subgroup)
class2(groupName, subgroup, ind)
```

Here is my data looks like:

```
class1
groupName  subgroup
     A      1
     A      2
     B      3
     C      4
     C      4
     C      5
     D      6


class2
groupName  subgroup IND
     A      1        Y     
     A      1        N
     A      2        Y
     A      2        N
     B      3        Y
     C      4        Y
     C      4        N
```

Now, I need to get the data that has the matching groupName and subGroup in both class1 and class2(Not necessarily distinct match). In addition to that the IND column should have pair of 'Y' and 'N' value for each subgroup in class 2.  Eg.In the above example GroupName A is qualified because A exists in both class1 and class2 and it has subgroup 1 and 2 exist in both class1 and class2 and IND column in class2 table has a pair of 'Y' and 'N' for each subgroup (i.e 1 and 2).

Rest of the records are not qualified because : Group B has subgroup 3 that exists in both class1 and class2 but it does not have 'Y' and 'N' pairs for subgroup 3 in class2. Group C and D are not qualified because its all subgroup (4,5) doesn't exist in class2.

I have more than 700,000 records on both table class1 and class2. Anyone has any idea what is the effective way to get this information.

Comment: Is it always true that class1 will have at least as many subgroups as class2? in other words, could you have E,7 in class1, and E,7,Y; E,7,N, E,8,Y .. in class 2?

Comment: No. It is not always true. Some time a group may exist in class1 but not in class2 and vice versa.

Comment: Suppose in your example (A,2,N) removed. Group "A" are qualified in such case? In other words, all subgroups of group *must* be qualified or one is enough?

Comment: All should be qualified. if we remove (A,2,N) then Group A is not qualified.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does this create what you need?

```
SELECT *
FROM class1 c1
JOIN class2 c2 ON c1.groupName = c2.groupName
        AND c1.subgroup = c2.subgroup
WHERE
    (
    SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT ind)
    FROM class2 c2a
    WHERE c2a.groupName = c1.groupName
        AND c2a.subgroup = c2a.subgroup
    ) = 2
  AND
    (
    SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT subgroup)
    FROM class1 c1b
    WHERE c1b.groupName = c1.groupName
    ) =
    (
    SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT subgroup)
    FROM class2 c2b
    WHERE c2b.groupName = c2.groupName
    )
```

Comment: This also works with my test data set as long as Y and N are the only characters in IND, but I think its easier to read than mine

Comment: I think it also doesn't work. Because you joined on groupName and subgroup, it will select group c and subgroup 4 since it exist on both class. But it should not be selected because subgroup 5 doesn't exist on class 2.

Comment: This doesn't work. It returns the data even if there is atleast one subgroup value matches in class1 with one subgroup value in class2 and there are other subgroup values that doesn't match; which should not be the case. The (Distinct) all subgroups should match in both class1 and class2.

Answer (score 0):

If it doesn't matter that the IND column has Y and N specifically, you could do this:

```
select t1.groupName from
( select count(class1.groupName) a, groupName from class1 group By groupName) t1
 inner join 
( select count(class2.groupName) a, groupName from class2 group by groupName) t2
on t1.groupName = t2.groupName and 2*t1.a = t2.a
```

If it does matter, you could probably modify the second inner query like so:

```
select count(class2.groupName) a, groupName from class2 group by groupName
  having  max(ind) = 'Y' and min(ind) = 'N'
```

Edit to support additional tests mentioned in comments:

```
select distinct t1.groupName from
( select count(class1.groupName) a, groupName, subgroup from class1 
  group By groupName, subgroup) t1
 inner join 
( select count(class2.groupName) a, groupName, subgroup from class2 
  group by groupName, subgroup
  having  max(ind) = 'Y' and min(ind) = 'N') t2
on t1.groupName = t2.groupName and t1.subgroup = t2.subgroup and 2*t1.a = t2.a
```

Comment: Thank You Mikeb. But I did not understand what 2*t1.a in above code. The IND column does matter. And you only joined on groupName but how this will ensure that the same subgroups in class1 also exists in class2. If there is any subgroups that exist in class1 and doesn't exist in class2 then it is not qualified and vice versa. I did not see where this condition is applied on the above code.

Comment: the count of the row grouping in class1 is half the size as the same count in class2 if the IND column has the right number of entries - so join on 2*t1.a = t2.a. You are correct about the grouping. If you had the right number of mismatched labels this would fail. It does work for your test data, however!

Answer (score 0):

Something like that must help ...

```
select 
  groupName
from (

  select -- Get number of good subgroups for each group
    groupName                      as groupName,
    subGroupCount                  as subGroupCount,
    sum( decode(ynCount, 2,1, 0) ) as goodGroupCount
  from (

      select -- Find which subgroups are good (contains both Y and N)
        c1set.groupName        as groupName,
        c1set.subGroup         as subGroup,
        c1set.subGroupCount    as subGroupCount,
        count(distinct c2.IND) as ynCount
      from
        (
          select -- Collect group/subgroup sets and get number of subGroups
            distinct 
              c1.groupName                        as groupName,
              c1.subGroup                         as subGroup,
              count(distinct c1.subGroup)
                over (parttition by c1.groupName) as subGroupCount
          from
            class1 c1
        )
               c1set,
        class2 c2
      where
        c2.groupName (+) = c1set.groupName
        and
        c2.subGroup (+) = c1set.subGroup
      group by
        c1set.groupName,
        c1set.subGroup,
        c1set.subGroupCount

    )
  group by
    groupName, subGroupCount

)
where
  subGroupCount = goodGroupCount
```

Sorry, I can't test this code now by myself. Please comment if you found any inconsistency.